# How to remove scratch org details from metadata

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, force-cli

When I pull down metadata from my production org (which is my devhub org), I have issues with scratch org metadata meddling with my repo. For example I have custom profiles that were created on the org the have

```
force-app/main/default/profiles/Custom User.profile-meta.xml        
In field: layout - no Layout named ActiveScratchOrg-Active Scratch Org Layout found (198:24)
```

This is because that profile now has the following:

```
<layoutAssignments>
    <layout>ActiveScratchOrg-Active Scratch Org Layout</layout>
</layoutAssignments>
```

I imagine if this was correctly created in a scratch org in the first place this may not have happened but will this lead to an issue when I deploy to production eventually? Not to mention that this continues the eternal salesforce cosmic battle for "the source of truth"

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of to do this is to build a package.xml using version 39.0 (?) or lower (so that you don't get *all* the profile metadata), and explicitly specify which object/fields you want to retrieve. This should provide you with usable profiles that you can use to deploy other places. Unfortunately, if you have a complicated setup, like we do, it may take a few days to properly build the package so you're not missing anything. A slightly better way *may* be to build classic package, add all of the elements you want to download, then retrieve it based on the package name (e.g. `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -p All -a 39.0`, where `All` is the name of the package you created, and `39.0` is the metadata API version to use).